# Cannot CMake NGraph on Raspberry Pi due to NGRAPH_VERSION

Tags: linux, tensorflow, cmake, openvino

The full build log is below

I am building following NGraph instructions on https://github.com/NervanaSystems/ngraph

Looking at these I am assuming these variables

```
NGRAPH_VERSION
NGRAPH_VERSION_SHORT
NGRAPH_API_VERSION
```

did not get set for some reason, even though the instructions never specifically require them to be set

My installation steps are:

```
git clone https://github.com/csullivan/ngraph.git
cd ngraph
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/openvino_files/ngraph/install
make -j install
```

I tried setting them manually in the command line and in the cmake file, adding

```
SET(NGRAPH_VERSION 1)
SET(NGRAPH_VERSION_SHORT 1)
SET(NGRAPH_API_VERSION 1)
```

but the error still did not go away. And i don't want to have to set the version manually every time.

Something else is wrong here, what am I doing wrong?
What command do I need to type in to make it build correctly?

Thanks,

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/openvino_files/ngraph/build $ cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/openvino_files/ngraph/install
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.20.1")
From https://github.com/csullivan/ngraph.git
CMake Error at cmake/Modules/git_tags.cmake:39 (string):
  string sub-command REGEX, mode MATCH needs at least 5 arguments total to
  command.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/Modules/git_tags.cmake:60 (NGRAPH_GET_TAG_OF_CURRENT_HASH)
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (NGRAPH_GET_VERSION_LABEL)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (list):
  list GET given empty list


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (list):
  list GET given empty list


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:29 (list):
  list GET given empty list


-- NGRAPH_VERSION
-- NGRAPH_VERSION_SHORT
-- NGRAPH_API_VERSION
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:41 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0042 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Installation directory: /home/pi/openvino_files/ngraph/install
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/openvino_files/ngraph/build/tbb
Scanning dependencies of target ext_tbb
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'ext_tbb'
[ 25%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'ext_tbb'
Cloning into 'tbb-src'...
Switched to a new branch 'tbb_2018'
Branch 'tbb_2018' set up to track remote branch 'tbb_2018' from 'origin'.
[ 37%] No patch step for 'ext_tbb'
[ 50%] No update step for 'ext_tbb'
[ 62%] No configure step for 'ext_tbb'
[ 75%] No build step for 'ext_tbb'
[ 87%] No install step for 'ext_tbb'
[100%] Completed 'ext_tbb'
[100%] Built target ext_tbb
CMake Error at src/ngraph/runtime/interpreter/CMakeLists.txt:27 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.


-- Found OpenMP_C: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP_CXX: -fopenmp (found version "4.5")
-- Found OpenMP: TRUE (found version "4.5")
-- Building Intel TBB: /usr/bin/make -j4 compiler=gcc tbb_build_dir=/home/pi/openvino_files/ngraph/build/src/ngraph/runtime/cpu/tbb_build tbb_build_prefix=tbb
CMake Warning (dev) at src/ngraph/runtime/cpu/CMakeLists.txt:125 (find_package):
  Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageName>_ROOT variables.
  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
  command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  CMake variable TBB_ROOT is set to:

    /home/pi/openvino_files/ngraph/build/tbb/tbb-src

  For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found TBB and imported target TBB::tbb
-- tools enabled
-- Adding unit test for backend INTERPRETER
-- Adding unit test for backend CPU
-- unit tests enabled
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/openvino_files/ngraph/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a validated OpenVINO toolkit release with all the components (including ngraph). You can download the latest Raspberry Pi OpenVINO version from https://download.01.org/opencv/2020/openvinotoolkit/2020.4/

The OpenVINO Raspberry Pi installation guide is available at
https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2020.4/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html